# React-Redux: Best way to restrict user access to certain pages if they are not logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to React/Redux, and I am working on a React application. I have been learning the basic concepts of Redux such as Store, Actions, Reducers, Middleware and the connect() function.

However, for some of the pages in my application, I want to allow only users that are logged in to be able to access them, otherwise they are redirected back to the home page of the application.

I was wondering what is the best method to be able to achieve this task? I have heard that React Router can be used to do this, but are there any better ways? Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested the router already, using it this works neatly n safely supposing the user is only set in the redux state, when properly authenticated in the login:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom':

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        user: state.user
    }
}

class MyPageWrapper extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        if(!this.props.user) this.props.history.push('/login');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <YourPage/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(MyPageWrapper));
```